# Maven не видет компилятор

Tags: java, maven

При том что паралельно запускаю другой проект и все работает.

```
E:\Projects\2017.03.19\bookcrud>mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building CRUD 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ crud ---
[INFO] Deleting E:\Projects\2017.03.19\bookcrud\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ crud ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ crud ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1251, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 6 source files to E:\Projects\2017.03.19\bookcrud\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.938 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-19T07:20:58+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/18M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project crud: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: JAVA_HOME какой?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Не что он пишет, а какой он? На какую директорию ведёт?

Comment: скорее всего я не настроил mvn deploy потому что mvn package работает

Comment: команда mvn package работает, все запускает, тестит, пакует и кадает в согласно настроики компилятора<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
          <warName>bookCrud</warName>
          <outputDirectory>e:\tomcat9\webapps\</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>